# How to fix alignment issue of text center in addition to other element on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have some ul li element. Here on hover of each element one new element is adding on the right side of the text. The alignment of the text is center but on hover when a new element is added on right side of it its alignment is getting changed. My problem is here, Alignment of text/new element should not effect on adding new element on hover. Here is the code below https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emvs2v?file=src%2Fstyles.css

### home.component.html

```html
<div style="width:50%" class="text-center box">
  <ul>
    <li [class.btn-success]="selectedIndex === 1" (mouseout)="removeIndex(1)"
        (mouseover)="setIndex(1)">Home <span class="float-right test">==></span>
    </li>
    <li [class.btn-success]="selectedIndex === 2" (mouseout)="removeIndex(2)"
        (mouseover)="setIndex(2)">Contact Us <span
      class="float-right test">==></span></li>
    <li [class.btn-success]="selectedIndex === 3" (mouseout)="removeIndex(3)"
        (mouseover)="setIndex(3)">Production<span
      class="float-right test">==></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button (click)="getSelect()">Submit</button>
```

### home.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;
  selectedIndex = 1;

  constructor () { }

  ngOnInit () {

  }

  setIndex (index: number) {
    this.selectedIndex = index;
  }

  removeIndex (index: number) {
    this.selectedIndex = null;
  }

  getSelect () {
    this.selectedIndex = 1;
  }
}
```

### css

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.test {
  display: none;
}

.btn-success .test {
  display: block;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.float-right {
  float: light;
}
```

Comment: Please add the html/js/css to a snippet (ctrl-M in the editor) to make it easier to debug and answer.

Comment: I added demo link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `display:none` and `display:block`, you are removing the item from the DOM, causing surrounding items to move.

You can fix this by using `opacity:0` and `opacity:1`, instead.

You can also use the `:hover` pseudo-class to greatly simply the code.

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.test {
  opacity: 0;
  float: right;
}

.btn-success:hover .test {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:150px;">
  <ul>
    <li class="btn-success">Home <span class="test">==></span></li>
    <li class="btn-success">Contact Us <span class="test">==></span></li>
    <li class="btn-success" >Production<span class="test">==></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the new element outside of the usual flow, e.g. using `position: absolute;`
Change your CSS to:

```css
ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
}
.test{
  display: none;    
}
.btn-success .test{
  display: block;
}
.text-center{
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  position: relative;
}
.float-right{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

You can check the working example here: https://angular-kcnrcg.stackblitz.io